# Want to put CSS arrows on adjacent divs pointing one direction

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create 3 divs across with arrows in the left and centre div pointing into the div to the right. I can get the first to point into the centre but as soon as I add the code for the centre and rename the div it disappears.

I think I may need some kind of `::before` operator to get it to work but not sure. Basically I would like a pink div with pink arrow pointing into a cream div with cream arrow pointing into a blue div:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
.hero-box-pink {
  position: relative;
  background: #ab255c;
}

.hero-box-pink:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(171,37,92,0);
  border-left-color: #ab255c;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.hero-box-cream {
  position: relative;
  background: #fcfbe3;
}

.hero-box-cream:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(252,251,227,0);
  border-left-color: #fcfbe3;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: where is your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: calc(100% /3);
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}
.first-box {
  background: #88b7d5;
}
.second-box {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.third-box {
  background: skyblue;
}
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
}
.arrow_box:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-left-color: #88b7d5;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.first-box.arrow_box:after {
  border-left-color: #88b7d5;
}
.second-box.arrow_box:after {
  border-left-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box first-box arrow_box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat.</div>
  <div class="box second-box arrow_box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat.</div>
  <div class="box third-box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla sapiente, quasi. Blanditiis ullam sint magnam, aspernatur optio vero explicabo quibusdam voluptatem beatae aliquid magni! Tempore numquam debitis, eum voluptatum atque.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this but 3 boxes across instead of 2!

Comment: @you need arrow for first two boxes ?

Comment: yes first one pointing into centre and centre pointing into right hand box.

Comment: @Flavour Monkey give me 5min to make it :)

Answer (score 0):

you may also use flex properties and rotate:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
}
p {
  padding: 2em;
}
p:first-of-type,
p:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  background: #AB255C;
}
p:last-of-type {
  background: #00617A;
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: 100%;
}
p:first-of-type:before {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  luctus, metus</p>
```

*rotating a pseudo element may allow you to draw borders or shadows or both around the whole element including the arrow.*

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  margin:1em;
}
p {
  padding:2em;
}
p:first-of-type,
p:last-of-type {
  position:relative;
  background:#AB255C;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px gray,0 0 5px 5px
}
p:last-of-type {
  background:#00617A;
}
p:before {
  content:'';
  background:inherit;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin:-1em -1.2em;
  height:2em;
  width:2em;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  right:100%;
  box-shadow:-3px 3px gray, -5px 5px 5px 
}
p:first-of-type:before {
  left:100%;
  box-shadow:3px -3px gray, 5px -5px 5px 
  
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  luctus, metus</p>
```

Here a **[demo to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PzoZZV)** or to fork